# Notification set big picture for tablet has displayed low quality

Tags: android, notifications

I have searched many times about `BigPictureImage().bigPicture(Bitmap b)`.
My problem is when I set `bigPicture(Bitmap b)` for Mobile, it's look good. But when app run on tablet, picture always have low quality, picture was not clearly look. I have put png image in correct drawable resource, in drawable-nodpi also has no effect. I think there is not different between Mobile and Tablet except screen size, it 's no problem in this situation.I have tried on 2 Mobile and 2 Tablet with different pixel density, both Tablets were wrong.

```
    private static Bitmap mContentBitmap = null;
    mContentBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.image); // png 972x522
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.quickpanel_list_ic_smart_call_filter);
    mBuilder.setTicker(null);
    mBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    mBuilder.setContentTitle(mContext.getString(R.string.smart_call_title));
    mBuilder.setContentText(contentString);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
            .bigPicture(mContentBitmap)
            .setSummaryText(contentString));

    NotificationManagerCompat notiManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(mContext);
    notiManager.notify(SMART_CALLS_FILTER_NOTIFICATION,mBuilder.build());
```

I have replaced method load bitmap image :

```
   mContentBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.image);
```

by

```
    mContentBitmap = getContentBitmap(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.image);
    public Bitmap getContentBitmap(Resources res, int resId){
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,resId,options);

        options.inSampleSize = 1;

        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,resId,options);
    }
```

but nothing changes, issue still happen. Anyone can help me fix this problem. Thank you for taking the time to read this question.
[Normal picture displaying in Mobile : 5 inch, 320 dpi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJH19.jpg)

[Wrong picture displaying in Tablet : 8 inch, 213 dpi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HECCA.jpg)

Comment: Hey, can you post a screenshot of mobile and tablet? May it's the issue of the picture.

Comment: Sorry, I am in office, can not upload file to internet. I will attach when go home soon.

Comment: Two image were attached, some Tablets value were more badly. Who can help me explaining why ?